Error mounting external LUKS HDD after dd from identical drive
I have two identical external drives used for backup (BK1_LUKS, BK2_LUKS). One has been formatted and encrypted, the other has been duplicated from the first one.
dd if=/dev/"first device" of=/dev/"second device"

Now I cannot connect both drives to my laptop because there's something conflicting.
I have changed the UUID of the second drive using the command
cryptsetup luksUUID /dev/<second drive> --uuid "newID"

but there's still something to fix.
After inserting the password I get this error (NOTE: I get the error ONLY if the other drive is connected):
An error occurred while accessing 'BK2_LUKS', the system responded: The requested operation has failed: Error mounting /dev/dm-2 at /run/media/x3m/bk2vault: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/luks-b047488c-099d-450b-818e-67f880b4dce0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error


Please check dmesg if it has a real error message for that generic mount messsage. If something relies on UUIDs you might have to change the filesystem UUID as well, however this by itself should not be causing that mount error...

You might have to change uuid from both disk and luks device. check your actual uuid using lsblk -o name,uuid,mountpoint

You are both right and I'm an idiot :) - dmesg was very clear "XFS (dm-2): Filesystem has duplicate UUID xxxxx-yyyy-....  - can't mount". Thank you!
